# vue-i18n Как задетектить локаль браузера и менять язык в зависимости от нее?

Tags: vue.js, i18n

Поставил i18n для vue. Задача такая: менять язык в зависимости от локалки браузера.

```
export let i18n = new VueI18n({
  locale: navigator.language,
  fallbackLocale: navigator.language,
  messages,
})
```

Это не работает для меня, выдает ошибку, что локаль не опеределена, а также ошибки `Cannot read property '_t' of undefined`.
Если локаль указывать так: `'en'` - все работает.

Comment: Описание проблемы следует писать для нетелепатов - подробнее, чем "не работает".

Comment: исправил, благодарю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо либо объявить языки в том же формате как у значения `navigator.language` - либо менять это значение, для соответствия формату объявления языков...

```js
const messages = {
  en: {
    message: { hello: 'Hello world' }
  },
  ru: {
    message: { hello: 'Привет, мир' }
  }
}; 
const i18n = new VueI18n({
  locale: window.navigator.language.slice(0, 2), 
  messages
}); 
new Vue({ i18n }).$mount('#app');
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <p>{{ $t("message.hello") }}</p>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-i18n/dist/vue-i18n.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @IvanNavi, Поясни пожалуйста, чем именно не устроило решение в данном ответе? (не в качестве претензии, просто мне любопытно  Критика в комментах может оказаться полезна и другим)

Comment: Я не писал о том, что меня что-то не устроило в Вашем ответе. Позабыл о том, что решение так и не отметил как за полезный ответ :) 
Глядя на Ваш ответ, понял, в чем была моя ошибка изначально, с чем накосячил. Писал вместо `window.navigator.language` просто `navigator.language`. Ваше решение в разы короче моего. Как оказалось, все проще, чем кажется

Comment: @IvanNavi, Я же не ради галочки) А ситуация с полным путем свойства - на самом деле интересная, у меня работало и без `window`. Вероятно, в твоем проекте есть код который объявляет переменную `navigator`. Вообще изначально я предположил суть проблемы что языки в объекте объявлены в формате `'ru'`, тогда как `navigator.language` возвращает строку в формате `'ru-RU'` :)

Comment: прошу прощения за беспокойство! сейчас использую  vue-i18n совместно со store. Код в сторе аналогичный тому, что написан здесь: https://medium.com/@helena.wuv/how-to-internationalize-your-next-nuxt-project-using-vue-i18n-d9c51e28a564. Может быть у Вас будут идеи, как мне вместо 'ru', в state locale записывать локаль браузера?

Comment: @ivannavi, Если стор vuex, то через мутацию, как описано в оф. документации этой библиотеки.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, насколько это правильная практика, но в хук `beforeMount()` я положил следующий код, и это сработало для меня.

```js
if (
      window.navigator.language === "en-US" ||
      window.navigator.browserLanguage === "en-US" ||
      window.navigator.userLanguage === "en-US" ||
      window.navigator.systemLanguage === "en-US" 
    ) {
      this.$i18n.locale = "en";
    } else if (
      window.navigator.language === "ru-RU" ||
      window.navigator.browserLanguage === "ru-RU" ||
      window.navigator.userLanguage === "ru-RU" ||
      window.navigator.systemLanguage === "ru-RU"
    ) {
      this.$i18n.locale = "ru";
    }
```